# does running wordpress as subdomain on iis website reduce performance

Tags: windows, iis, performance, wordpress

So it seems the usual googling won't suffice here for this question.

Lets break it down.
I have a main IIS website running on https://www.mymainsite.com
I have a wordpress website running as a subdomain on the same server (Windows IIS 10.0) https://www.mymainsite.com/blog

Now when I refresh the broswer for the IIS website, there is a process called CGI/FactCGi which I think controls the php code side of things and it chews up 35% of the processor for a second or two.
I would expect it to do this if I refreshed a page on wordpress, but https://www.mymainsite.com should be controlled by IIS worker process.

Can anyone elaborate on this?
Is running the wordpress website on IIS as a subdomain https://www.mymainsite.com/blog adding a performance impact on https://www.mymainsite.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It *shouldn't*, but it looks like:

- You've possibly configured it as a folder, not a subdomain (websites, including sub.domain.com s, are made IIS Applications by default)
- You've not marked that folder as an application, so it shares the parent URL's configuration
- When installing WordPress it's adjusted the parent site configuration and done something like "map all incoming requests to PHP-CGI" or similar.

It's possible that you could mark the folder as an Application (right-click, convert to Application) - but I think the configuration you need might need to be in place before that change.

If CGI processes are running on every request, copying the relevant handler mappings from the site level to the application level (and then removing from the site level) might do the trick.

IIS folders run as part of their parent website configuration; IIS Apps have their own distinct per-app configuration, so if the configuration needs to be variable (and isolated - Apps can also run in their own App Pool to improve reliability), using Apps is the way to go.

Comment: Hi TristanK thanks for the feed back, I did some more testing and yep every request to IIS triggers the CGI process, first the IIS worker processes the request then right after that's finished the CGI process does it's processing. Tested this on a dev site so I know I'm the only one making the request.

I don't seem to have convert to application option.
Do you have guides handy for some of these suggestions?
Also can't give u upvote until 15 rep :(

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis - quick overview of the differences between item types. And don't sweat the upvote!